# How to split DataFrame into FirstName column, and LastName column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

so I am sifting through a dataset with pandas in Python 3.6. I'm using the Spyder IDE, and the excel sheet contains the following columns:

```
[basic info][1]
```

This is reading an excel(xls) file. The column really in question is the "Customer Name" column. For this, I want to split the Customer Name column into two separate columns, Firstname, and LastName. However, when I try this:

```
df["FirstName"] = df[df["Customer Name"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0])]
```

I get this as an error:

```
KeyError: "['Claire' 'Claire' 'Darrin' ..., 'Dave' 'Dave' 'Chris'] not in index"
```

However, when I do this:

```
snames = df[df["Customer Name"].apply(lambda x: x.startswith("S"))]
```

It returns all customer names that start with S.

I've tried replacing all spaces with underscores, yet I still get the same error. I've also skimmed through the data in excel, and it doesn't seem like there are any spaces missing, or that I notice.

So I'm wondering, how can I split these two into separate columns? I'm not too worried about hyphenation, or other oddities (however you are free to help if you want to).

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['FirstName'] = df['Customer Name'].str.split().str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with assign to new columns if always one first and always one last names:

```
df[["FirstName", "LastName"]] = df["Customer Name"].str.split(expand=True)
```

More general solution is assign to new `DataFrame`, if multiple witespaces get 3 or more columns - but then is problem distinguish which 2 names are first or which 2 are last:

```
df1 = df["Customer Name"].str.split(expand=True)
#set columns names
#df1 = ["FirstName","LastName","Name"]
```

---

Error is expected, because:

```
df["Customer Name"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0])
```

return `FirstName` instead boolean, so not possible filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Answer (score 0):

If name FullName column in LastName, FirstName format:

to get last name:

```
df["LastName"] = df["FullName"].apply(lambda x: x[0:x.find(",")])
```

(above takes everything from start of string until comma, not including comma)

to get first name:

```
df["FirstName"] = df["FullName"].apply(lambda x: x[x.find(",")+2:])
```

(above takes everything in string 2 characters after comma (including comma) until end of string)